# Hibernate search Monitoring the Index process

Tags: indexing, lucene, hibernate-search

I am using Hibernate search to index Data from Postgresql datenbank, while the process takes really long i want to display Process bar to estimate how long it will take to finish indexing, i also want to display which Entity is being indexed.
First i enabled jmx_enabled and generate_statistics in my Persistence.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.search.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.search.jmx_enabled" value="true"/>
```

then added the processMotitor to FullTextSession in my Index Class like this

```
MassIndexerProgressMonitor monitor = new SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor();

FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(em.unwrap(Session.class));

fullTextSession.getStatistics();

fullTextSession.createIndexer(TCase.class).progressMonitor(monitor).startAndWait();
```

the Problem is that i still don't know how to print the Process results on console while Indexing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to documentation of [SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.5/api/org/hibernate/search/batchindexing/impl/SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor.html) you need to have **INFO** level enabled at package level org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl or class level org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor

Can you check your log level?

Comment: I enabled  INFO level in log4j and its woking thank you so much